# What to do if a query result is too big

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm using mysql connector of python3 to query from a mysql database. I have so many data that if I collect the recent 7 days' data, the size of the query will be over 10GB and therefore forced my python script to be killed. I think usually we can stream the result however I don't find a way to stream the query result in mysql conncetor. Is there any other way that I can solve the problem?

Comment: perhaps jam it out to a file via `select into`. That said, before marching into an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what in the world are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can use the connector cursor and `fetchmany` function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchmany.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anthony Kong's comment is correct. To solve this issue, we can do `fetchmany` function from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchmany.html

After digging into the code a little bit, I found that the `fetchmany` function calls many `fetchone` to achieve "fetchmany". So I decide to use fetchone at last. Also fetchone comes with an example on the document https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't fetch the result set in one go. You can do one of the following or the combination of these:

1. Use `LIMIT, OFFSET` to generate multiple files using `SELECT into`
2. Use Date/Hour Functions to generate multiple files using `SELECT into`

`cat` all the generated files into one file using `cat hugedata_* > hugedata.csv`